# Настройка php на apache для загрузки файлов

Tags: apache, php

Вопрос: правда ли что на максимальный размер загружаемой информации через POST влияют три параметра:

```
post_max_sizeupload_max_filesizememory_limit
```

?

И сразу: чтобы их переопределить для конкретного сайта, куда надо кидать php.ini? В корень?В etc данного сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В линях обычно `/etc/php/apache2-php(версия-пхп)/php.ini`

а вообще, создайте в корне сайта файл, к примеру, с именем `pi.php` и напишите в него

```
<?phpphpinfo();?>
```

и откройте в браузере, там будет путь до файла `php.ini`

Comment: опять же, если это хостинг, то читайте faq хостинга, у меня, например, файл php.ini выдается по требованию, т.е. поумолчанию пользовательского нет.

Answer (score 1):

php.ini остается в папаке php

В Windows в файле конфигурации apache (httpd.conf) пишутся строки

*LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"AddType application/x-httpd-php .phpPHPIniDir "C:/php"*

В linux не помню